# mallocing string in C

Tags: c, char, malloc, heap-memory

I'm not quite sure I get how `malloc` works exactly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

 char * string = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
 string = "abc";

 int * test = (int*) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
 *(test) = 5;
 *(test + 1) = 6;


}
```

I expected this to output an error since the value I appoint to string is bigger than just one char yet it seems to compile just fine.

I have a few questions:

1. Where would 'string' be saved now? is it on memory spaces on the heap after the one space I allocated ?
2. Why is does the char let me appoint directly and the int only via pointer?

I'm really not sure what I'm doing here

Comment: Why are you [casting the return value of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm following a MIT ocw course and the ppt example used this but your right this seems pretty stupid thanks for the extra information

Comment: `*(test + 1) = 6;` writes out of bounds

Comment: What you are writing is undefined behavior.  To be honest, if you don't know how to properly assign a string to a character pointer, you really aren't ready for `malloc`.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer No one was ready for `malloc`, let's be honest.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer It might have been a little bit too ambitious of me considering I've only programmed a few small projects in garbage collected languages :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answers:

You probably want this:

```
char *string = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);  // allocate space for 100 chars
strcpy(string, "abc");  // copy the "abc" into the memoory location pointer by string
```

instead of this:

```
char *string = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));   // << this allocates only a single char
string = "abc";
```

And

```
*(test) = 5;
*(test + 1) = 6;
```

is better written as:

```
test[0] = 5;
test[1] = 6;
```

which is strictly equivalent, it's just a matter of readability.

**Allocating too few memory:**

If you allocate memory for only 1 char as here:

```
char *string = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));  // allocate space 1 char
strcpy(string, "abc");  // copy the "abc" into the memoory location pointer by string
```

then your program will still compile fine, but at runtime the string will be copied partly to non allocated memory, which results in undefined behaviour (google "undefined behaviour").

Comment: but I'm only allocating space for one char wouldn't it be possible then that when I allocate space for another variable that the adresses holding "bc\0" would be overwritten? EDIT: yeah you answered before my comment was finished thanks

Comment: Magic numbers are extremely bad practice.  It's a bad idea to start new programmers off with bad habits.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer you are right, but I didn't want to overcomplicate things, the OP's program being just a test program anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This code

```
string = "abc";
```

assigns the address of the string constant `"abc"` to the `string` variable, which is a `char *`.  The address of the memory returned from your `malloc()` call - which was in `string` - gets overwritten and lost.

Answer (score 2):

> Where would 'string' be saved now?

```
char * string = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
string = "abc";
```

`string` now points to "abc" (a literal string) - the initial dynamic allocation (in the heap) has been lost track and you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a real-life example.

Suppose Mr. A lives at the address "abc". Now, some Mr. B starts living at some address "xyz". Soon, Mr. B address "xyz" is renamed to "abc". Now, if you go to the address "abc", you will meet Mr. B, not Mr. A. But, this don't mean that Mr. A place is demolished. It simply means that Mr. A's living area now has no reachable address and is lost.

Similarly, the memory you `malloc`'ed to `string` and then re-assigned the `string` to "abc", means, `string` earlier had an address to the `malloc`'ed memory. Later, your "abc" is written to some memory and the address to that memory is stored in `string`. Thus, losing the `malloc`'ed memory forever which is called Memory Leak.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will not prevent you to do something that is allowed - however you're likely to get a warning for the 1) since `string` is assigned and not used before being re-assigned (provided that the compiler is requested to output the relevant warnings).

As for 2), you call a function which happens to be `malloc`, with an argument that happens to be too small for the usage you want to do with the pointer returned by `malloc`, but since the syntax is correct, the compiler doesn't complain.

Answer to

1) `string` points to `"abc"` and the previous value from `malloc` is lost

2) you could do `test[0] = 5;` as well.

The behavior for 2) is undefined behavior (access an array out of bounds).

Answer (score 0):

At first there was allocated dynamically memory with the requested size of one character.

```
char * string = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

And then the pointer was reassigned with the address of the first character of the string literal "abc".

```
string = "abc";
```

As result the address of the dynamically allocated memory was lost and there is a memory leak in the program.

If the program would written in C++ then this statement

```
string = "abc";
```

could arise a compiler diagnostic message because string literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays and the pointer `string` shuld be declared like

```
const char *string;
```

As for the string literal then they have static storage duration and are allocated before main gets the control. Usually all string literals are places in the so-called string literal pool.

Instead of this statement

```
string = "abc";
```

you could write

```
strcpy( string, "abc" );
```

In this case the program has undefined behavior. However it can continue to work successfully due to the feature that usually the function `malloc` allocates minimum memory extent equal to the value of the paragraph that is equal to 16 bytes.

Comment: This is a C question. Behaviour of C++ code is irrelevant

Comment: @M.M There is no any "irrelevant" information. In C 1) pointers also can be declared with qualificator const that is in C can be used the same approach as in C++; 2) any comparison of the same construction in C and C++ are very useful and helps to understand better  C and C++.